# Why Cannot find module 'request-promise' ? ( Runtime.ImportModuleError)

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I create a simple NodeJS project and want to upload it as an aws lambda, but I get this error when I hit Test:

```
{
  "errorType": "Runtime.ImportModuleError",
  "errorMessage": "Error: Cannot find module 'request-promise'\nRequire stack:\n- /var/task/index.js\n- /var/runtime/UserFunction.js\n- /var/runtime/index.js",
  "trace": [
    "Runtime.ImportModuleError: Error: Cannot find module 'request-promise'",
    "Require stack:",
    "- /var/task/index.js",
    "- /var/runtime/UserFunction.js",
    "- /var/runtime/index.js",
    "    at _loadUserApp (/var/runtime/UserFunction.js:100:13)",
    "    at Object.module.exports.load (/var/runtime/UserFunction.js:140:17)",
    "    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/runtime/index.js:43:30)",
    "    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1085:14)",
    "    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1114:10)",
    "    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:950:32)",
    "    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:790:14)",
    "    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:76:12)",
    "    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47"
  ]
}
```

[image: aws lambda error]

I import every think, but the lambda can't find modules that already exist in node_modules.

the structure of my project is like this:

```
project_name>
  node_modules
  index.js
  package.json
  package-lock.json
```

**index.js**

```
let request = require("request-promise");

exports.handler = async () => {
   // my functions
   ...
}
```

Do you have any idea how to solve this issue please!

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by installing request

```
npm install request --save
```

then I deployed the project and it seems every thing is ok.

Comment: Also, you can consider to use lambda layers https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/using-lambda-layers-to-simplify-your-development-process/